# How to use Calculated Route ID to Load Interactive Bing Map v8 with that Route?

Tags: bing-maps

I have used the Bing Maps REST service for driving directions to get a list of route options.  In these returned routes, I receive a Route ID as `id`.  I am able to then use the route ids to load static image maps, one for each route option.

[Here is one example with the Bing API key removed](http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/Routes/driving/?key=BING_API_KEY_HERE&ms=1064%2C300&wp.0=Yonkers%2C%20NY%3B79%3BA&wp.1=North%20Eastham%2C%20MA%3B80%3BB&rid=v69%2Ch1711786854%2Ci1%2Ca0%2Ccen-US%2CdAAAAAAAAAAA1%2Cy0%2Cs3%2Cm1%2Co1%2Ct4%2CwLjvEP2x3RECSIFwBhXlSwA2~AoeaOLnx9SkmAADgASLX-z4A0~WW9ua2VycywgTlk1~~~~v10%2CweXjPgeXuREC30QDeAn9RwA2~AoeaOLkB94UoAADgAR5c_D4A0~Tm9ydGggRWFzdGhhbSwgTUE1~~~~v10%2Ck0).

Route ID can be seen in the response as an example here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg636957.aspx

Given that I can load a static image map using the route ID, how can I load the Interactive Bing Maps v8 Controls with that route ID?  The [DirectionsManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt750375.aspx) Class does not take a route ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route ID is not a documented or supported part of the Bing Maps platform. You shouldn't use that for the REST services, let alone any of the other Bing Maps API's. The REST services that's in route options as documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff701724.aspx All of these same route options are available in [Directions module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt748655.aspx) of the Bing Maps V8 interactive SDK.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for getting a list of routes using the REST API and then loading a specific route on a V8 Interactive Map or even on a static image map?

Comment: Like this? http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#RestServices_MultipleRoutes

Comment: I looked at that example.  If I retrieve a route via the REST API for driving directions between NY and MA (for example), I get a route with 1241 unique locations in RoutePath.  I then need to pass along all of those to another page for the Interactive Map to hand draw them, which is too much, AND then I might have a duplicate appearing in the itineraryContainer from the DirectionsManager control.  Route ID would be ideal here.  Is the data source the same between the REST API and v8 map and can the route index be trusted if both make the same request?

Comment: All you need is the route options and waypoints you used. You can then pass these into the REST service or directions module of the interactive map control.